# Module doesn't provide an export named "default"

Tags: javascript

There are a two similar question but their solutions either are a work around that stops using modules or don't solve my issue. The modules don't seem to be working as expected. I'm running this through a local host server, using node and I just updated node. I'm sure the cause of this error, so I put all the files below.

I'm getting an error stating my drawLine module isn't exporting something called default -why?

The error it throws is:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module './drawLine.js' does not provide 
an export named 'default'
```

In addition if I change the drawLine module to just export normally using export {drawLine} and import using import {drawLine} from "./drawLine.js";

It throws the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module './drawLine.js' does not provide 
an export named 'drawLine'
```

app.js:

```
 import drawLine from "./drawLine.js";

 console.log(imports.drawLine);
 let line= imports.drawLine(0,100);
 let body= document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
 body.append(line);
```

drawLine.js

```
function drawLine(x,y){
   let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
   let canvasContext= canvas.getContext("2d");
   canvasContext.beginPath();
   canvasContext.moveTo(0,0);
   canvasContext.lineTo(x,y);
   canvasContext.stroke();

  return canvas;
}

export default drawLine;
```

index.html:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
      <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">

      </head>
      <body>
          <p>hello</p>
          <script type="module" src="app.js"></script>
      </body>
  </html>
```

nodeServer.js

```
 let HTTP = require("http");
 let fs = require("fs");

  let requestListener = function(req, res){
      let url = req.url;
      console.log(url);

      if(url === "/index.html"){
          fs.readFile("index.html", function(err, data){
             if(err){
                  throw err;
             }

              else{
                 res.setHeader("Content-Type", "Text/html");
                  res.write(data);
                  res.end();
              }
          });
      }
      else if(url === "/app.js" || url === "/drawLine.js" || url === "/canterSet.js") {
          fs.readFile("app.js", function(err, data){
              if(err){
                 throw err;
              }

              else{
                  res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/javascript");
                  res.write(data);
                  res.end();
              }
           });
      }
 }

  let server = HTTP.createServer(requestListener);

  server.listen(8080);
```

Comment: `url === "/app.js" || "/drawLine.js" || "/canterSet.js"` is not how you check multiple values

Comment: ty for see that just fixed

Comment: Your server is serving app.js when it gets a request for drawline.js. should be `fs.readFile(url,...`

Comment: Also i have no idea how node is resolving the circular dependency where app.js is importing itself

Comment: Have you told Node to enable modules?: https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_enabling - They are not enabled by default.